# How to change several files names in a specific folder on Python?

Tags: python, path, rename

so I've been using the following code to change the file name of all of the files in a specific folder.

```
import os
[os.rename(f,f.replace('20180810','2018_08_10')) for f in os.listdir()]
```

The issue I'm having is that whenever I use this code, I have to save a copy of it and paste it in the folder where the files are present. I'd like to be able to have a general code where I can specify the path without having to be in that folder. I tried the following but for some reason it says it can't find the file:

```
path = 'E:/CSVFILES/20180808/'
[os.rename(f,f.replace('20180810','2018_08_10')) for f in os.listdir(path)]
```

If I run os.listdir(path), it runs fine and it displays the files in the folder, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir` lists all the files in the directory, but without the full path, and `os.replace` requires a full path if the file isn't in the working directory.  Instead, use `iglob`, which returns full paths:

```
>>> from glob import iglob
>>> path = 'E:/CSVFILES/20180808/*'
>>> for f in iglob(path):
>>>     os.rename(f, f.replace('20180810','2018_08_10'))
```

Edit: Because your files are in a location that contains the same text that you're trying to replace, you can use `basename` and `join` to only replace the text in the filename:

```
>>> from glob import iglob
>>> from os.path import basename, join
>>> path = 'E:/CSVFILES/20180808'
>>> for f in iglob(join(path, "*")):
>>>     os.rename(f, join(path, basename(f).replace('20180810','2018_08_10')))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I get the following error when I try that:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'E:/CSVFILES/20180808\\ismRawTec_G10_20180808.csv' -> 'E:/CSVFILES/2018_08_08\\ismRawTec_G10_2018_08_08.csv'

Comment: That's because your files in are in a directory called `20180808`, so your `replace` method tries to replace both, and write files to a directory that doesn't exist.  You can fix this with the `basename` function - see my edit above.

Comment: Hi @Julian if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.